# remove ViewController from parent screen stays black

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm having trouble with removing a modal view.
I want to show (after pressing a button) a my own SendMailViewController which it self shows  a MFMailComposeViewController. Then and after pressing cancel of send, in my own SendMailView controller in didFinishWithResult i do a [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] and that works. The MFMailComposeView goes away.
But then the screen stays black....it think i also have to remove my SendMailViewController from it's parent. That's where i pushed the button...even after [self removeFromParentViewController] it still stays black...

Where do i go wrong?

And yes i would like the extra viewcontroller (SendMailViewController) because that controller will become the delegate of MFMailComposeViewController. Otherwise my caller (controller with the button) get's to much responsibility. Or do i also go wrong here?

Thanks,

/jr00n

```
- (IBAction)tapExportButton:(id)sender
{

    SendMailViewController *sendMailController = [[SendMailViewController alloc]init];

    [self presentViewController:sendMailController animated:YES completion:^()    {[sendMailController openMailDialog];}];

    [sendMailController release];

}
```

SendMailViewController:

```
- (void)openMailDialog
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
     ...
        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
....
 // Remove the mail view
 // first i did this:
 // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self removeFromParentViewController];}];
}
```

Comment: did you do this ? mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

Comment: yes i did, i've updated my example code, and the delegating works. In that delegate i do the [self dismissModalViewController...]

Comment: I'm not sure why your view is black, but you don't need the removeFromParentViewController. Modal views, I'm pretty sure, don't have a parent view controller.

Comment: @jr00n, yes you't dont need [self removeFromParentViewController];. just pass nil.

Comment: in your didFinishWithResult method, remove this:-> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self removeFromParentViewController];}]; try adding this:-> [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]}];

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama Yes!! Give that man a cigar!! Great stuff. This community rocks! In less then 12 minutes solved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self removeFromParentViewController];}];` in your didFinishWithResult method.
Remove that line and add the following line,

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]}];
```

That make sure we dismiss the controller after dismissing the MailController