# In iOS prevent RootViewController to become God like by extra 'controller' to display MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370694/remove-viewcontroller-from-parent-screen-stays-black) a question about the same issue before, and the solutions worked, but it was not a compatible iOS 4.3 solution, and I thought my design is not the right one.

Now I want to show a MFMailComposeView(Controller) as a modal view on top of my RootView(Controller) when i press a button. And instead of making it the delegate i want to make a simple NSObject which implements the  protocol.
Who is also capable to show the MFMailComposeView(Controller) in the RootViewController.

I am trying this design/solution which gives me memory allocation/access problems.

RootViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)tapExportButton:(id)sender
{
    SendMailController *sendMailController = [[SendMailController alloc]initWithParentViewController:self];
    [sendMailController openMailDialog];
    [sendMailController release];
}
```

SendMailController.h

```
@interface SendMailController : NSObject <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parentViewController;
- (void)openMailDialog;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIViewController* parentViewController;

@end
```

SendMailController.m

```
#import "SendMailViewController.h"

@implementation SendMailController

@synthesize parentViewController = _parentViewController;

- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parentViewController
{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.parentViewController = parentViewController;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.parentViewController = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)openMailDialog
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        ...
        mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
        [mailer release];
    }
}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    ...
    // Remove the mail view
    [controller.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

When I set a breakpoint in the delegation method, it crashes already before that.
Is is something with the delegate property of mailer (MFMailComposeViewController)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create your instance of `SendMailController` and try to show the composer view, and then you release the `SendMailController`. This causes it to be deallocated. It looks like it works because the composer view is on screen - this is because it has been retained by the `presentModalViewController` call.

To fix, you need to retain your instance of `SendMailController` and release it when the composer has been dismissed.

The correct way to do it (and required if you use ARC, and you should use ARC) is to provide a delegate callback to tell the owner that it's finished - which kind of makes the class pointless if all it does is wrap the composer.

The cheating way (which only works when not using ARC, and which you need to be very careful with) is to have your object retain itself when it presents the composer and release itself when the composer is dismissed.

The underlying problem being your root view controller containing all the logic, you should look at using child view controllers (if a single screen holds all your UI). Usually though, your root view should be the simple class (like a master list of options) and the views it presents would be more complex (the detail views). You need to look at ensuring that the appropriate class owns the responsibility for each screen of UI.

Comment: Wain, thanks! You're spot on that an extra delegation is a waste than it is better to let the RootViewController handle it all.

Comment: Wain, thanks! You're spot on that an extra delegation is a waste than it is better to let the RootViewController handle it all. In the last part you spoke about more controllers to offload the RootViewController. That was exactly what i was looking for, and hoped to solved that with an extra controller. I can make it a UiViewController, but that an unneeded UIView. So because it's a modal view, it belongs to another's UIView controller? Or should a make a UIViewController with a transparent view and add in that new UIViewController do a presentModalViewController?

Comment: And yes Wain, i should use ARC! But if i want to support the iPad1 users with 4.3 iOS i can't....or do i have that wrong?

Comment: Only weak is not supported on iOS4 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html so i can use ARC, thanks